# javascript send variable to function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I want to SetTimeout and return variable name 'MyVAR' to timer:function('MyVAR') and I can't to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = function () {
    function aa(){

    }
    return{
      timer: function (MyVAR) {
        setTimeout("a.timer(MyVAR);", 1000);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    a.timer(MyVAR);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you su- ... That's woking!